# Insert two or more parameter in pathname in batch

Tags: batch-file

I have a probably quite simple question, on whose solution I do not come so fast even after google. I want to define a variable in batch that consists of several variables. For example like this:

```
set logPath="C:/path/"
set version=2
```

The final path should look like this:

```
"C:/path/logfile2".
```

What will the corresponding statement in bath look like?

Comment: Change `set logPath="C:/path/"` to ```Set "logPath=C:\path"``` and `set version=2` to ```Set "version=2"```, then you can use ```"%logPath%\logfile%version%"``` for your final joined string path. Please note, I have changed your URI or Unix path separators from `/` to ```\```, because that is what Windows and its purpose built tools uses.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this

```
SET "full_path=%logPath%logfile%version%"
```